# Why are the following graphs discontinuous at $f(0)$ (epsilon-delta)

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

[image]

The caption for graph (f) is "Infinite jump". The caption for graph (h) is "Infinitely many infinite jumps".

The graphs are meant to illustrate that we can pick arbitrarily small intervals around $0$ in which the function value $f(x)$ is at some $x$ at least a predetermined value $h$ away from $f(0)$.

I don't understand how the two graphs illustrate the above point because:

For graph (f), given any $h$, if we move along the $x$-axis, then clearly we will eventually reach an $x$ such that $f(x)<h$. I can only conclude that the illustration to work, given any $h$, we are allowed to only move closer to $x=0$ to find an $f(x)$ that is less than $h$. Is this correct or did I misinterpret the illustration/not getting some subtle point?

For graph (g), I have no idea how to interpret it in the context of the intended illustration since $h$ is not given and I am not sure the purpose of the dotted diagonal arrow. Please help me explain how this graph is consistent with the intended illustration.

This material is actually a prelude to the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, so I would also appreciate it if you can show me how the two graphs fail to meet that definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (one-sided) continuity of the function at 0 is given as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{f(x)}=f(0)$. And if we're using an epsilon-delta definition of the limit, then that means $\left(\forall\epsilon>0\right)\left(\exists\delta>0\right):\forall x \left(x-0<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon\right)$

To put it in plainer English, it means that if you pick some arbitrary value $\epsilon$ and draw the horizontal lines $y=f(0)\pm \epsilon$ (i.e. lines a height of $\epsilon$ above and below $y=f(0)$), then you can also choose a value $\delta$ such that when you draw the line $x=\delta$, then all values of $f(x)$ between that line and the x-axis are also contained in the two horizontal lines. Then, if you pick a smaller value of $\epsilon$, then you can still find another value of $\delta$ that makes that work.

So in the first example, if you choose $\epsilon=h$, then no matter how you choose your $\delta$ you're going to find that the function escapes those bounds. This is also true of the second example, but in that case it shows that you can't just look at a single value of $x$ to test whether you can bound it - there's a distinct series of values of the function that *is* converging on $f(0)$, but outside of those values the function is going everywhere.